# Label will not set when form loads

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to set a label to the value of a registry key so that when the person loads the form up it sets the label to there registry key value. It doesn't set and is just the default text with is No Key Found Or An Error Has Occurred. I get A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll as a error in the immediate window.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim readValue As String
    readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
    ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA", "KEY", Nothing)
    Label3.Text = readValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

> MsgBox("The value is " & readValue)

Just to check if it's something at that "KEY".

Then:
Add this:

```
Dim bytes as Byte() = CType(readValue, Byte())
str = BitConverter.ToString(bytes)
label.Text = str
```

Comment: Either something wrong at that registry key, or, try to put a button that calls that function, just to testing purposes.

Comment: It says Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: Yep its like, 11,42,29,23,24,54,65,56,75,57 Etc. I have changed it to integer and byte but its the same error.

Comment: So, let me understand, you need to read a few byte from the registry and display them as text ? or convert those bytes to string and then display it ???

Comment: Display it as text. Sorry for the misunderstanding. So if in my registry my key was 99,33,23,53,53,76,85,12 then the label would say 99-33-23-53-53-76-85-12

Comment: Nope, still not working. Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.                Error 2 Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
readvalue = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(".etc..",));
```